# Storing large descriptions / text in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am having an issue with storing descriptions in my mysql database.

I am storing it as TEXT and collations: latin1_swedish_ci

I am inserting the text with HTML and the output is fine except for these ? with a square around it.  This only displays in a few random spots throughout the text.

Is there a correct way to store this text (with HTML)?

Comment: character set mismatch - unless you're sending in latin1_swedish text, you're going to get corrupted output, because the char sets don't match. Your tables should match exactly the character set of the data you're using, or you need to have conversion logic between the two.

Comment: go utf8 and forget all problems

Comment: which UT8 do i choose in mysql?  there are so many...I tried UT8_general_ci and it did not work...

Comment: utf8 is the only one. However you are talking about collation which is an addition to the utf8. Regarding this one, choose utf8_unicode_ci. However this is not enough. You must also set up utf8 in your source and everywhere in mysql and also in php script / db connection, etc. You can find lots of info about that on SO

Comment: You must use the same charset for inserting data into mysql and selecting from it. What do you use for inserting? Which php methode? PDO, MYSQLi or simple MYSQL?